# how to process multiple functions on several subgroups efficiently?

Tags: r, function, extract

I am a novice using R:) I am trying to 1)extract 27 subgroups(dertermined by 3 columns g1,g2,g3) out of a database and 2)plot a Hist diagramme then 3)calculate the 0.05 Quantile for each subgroup. What i until now did is to conduct the process one by one using the following code, but it is not efficient. Does anyone know some better solution for it? Any help will be very appreciated!

some of my codes:

```
g111<-residQ_grouped[residQ_grouped$g1==1&residQ_grouped$g2==1&residQ_grouped$g3==1,]  
g112<-residQ_grouped[residQ_grouped$g1==1&residQ_grouped$g2==1&residQ_grouped$g3==2,]                                                                                                    
until to(27 times)  
g333<-residQ_grouped[residQ_grouped$g1==3&residQ_grouped$g2==3&residQ_grouped$g3==3,]
```

For plot i did:
        `hist(g111$value,breaks=300,freq=T,border=F,col="lightblue",xlim=c(-0.3,0.3),...)` again i need do     27 times manually.

and for 0.05 Quantile the same:

```
Quant_g111  <-  quantile(g111$tau0.50,0.05)  
Quant_g112  <-  quantile(g112$tau0.50,0.05)  
Quant_g113  <-  quantile(g113$tau0.50,0.05)
```

...27 times

below is an example of the database structure:

```
Value   g1  g2  g3    
1   1   1   1  
2   1   1   2  
1   1   1   3  
9   1   2   1  
6   1   2   2  
2   1   2   3  
4   1   3   1  
7   1   3   2  
9   1   3   3  
2   2   1   1  
3   2   1   2  
6   2   1   3  
8   2   2   1  
1   2   2   2  
9   2   2   3  
2   2   3   1  
8   2   3   2  
8   2   3   3  
3   3   1   1  
8   3   1   2  
1   3   1   3  
5   3   2   1  
3   3   2   2  
5   3   2   3  
5   3   3   1  
4   3   3   2  
8   3   3   3
```

.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I might do (and I will firmly resist creating 27 * 3 objects in my workspace):

```
 g.grouped <- split(residQ_grouped, interaction(residQ_grouped[, 2:4]) )
 # For testing I created an expanded dataset
 residQ_grouped <- cbind(residQ_grouped , tau=rnorm(27*10))
```

This will create a 27 page packet of histograms. (You might consider using `layout` to put 9 on a page.)

```
 pdf("quant_output.pdf", onefile=TRUE)
   lapply(names(g.grouped), function(x){ hist(g.grouped[[x]]$tau, 
          main=bquote(Histgram~of~.(x)), breaks=5, freq=T, border=F, 
          col="lightblue", xlim=c(-3,3) ) } )
 dev.off()
```

Presumably the 'tau' column is in there, although it's not clear where. Assuming it's a column in the same dataframe then:

```
 g.quans <- lapply( lapply(g.grouped, "[[", "tau") , # first extract the columns
                    quantile, 0.05)                # then calculate the quantiles
```

Comment: sorry, i still have two small questions about that: 1)when i run the code below it comes error:    >write.csv(g.grouped,file="g.grouped.csv")
Fehler in data.frame(`1.1.1` = list(Firm = c(38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2043, 2180, 2200, 2164, 2220, 2221, 2219, 2252, 2294   2) >lapply(g.grouped$tau0.50, hist, breaks=300,freq=T,border=F,col="lightblue",xlim=c(-0.3,0.3),xlab="Cash Flow shock",ylab="Frequency")
>list()      could you please tell me how can i see the graphs? i tried, but i cannot figure it out. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: It should print them to the interactive graphics device. You should be able to scroll backward ( on a Mac it's cmd-backarrow), but I just realized that on my device that would only be a maximum of 15 graphs, so we need to come up with a strategy that prints these to a multipage file. Will add that code.